How does customs clearance work when you fly into Norway through Oslo, then have your luggage checked through to a regional airport?
If I am flying with Norwegian Air from Dubai to Alta (ALF), with a connection in Oslo (OSL), on a single ticket, how will I clear customs for my luggage? Will my luggage be handled automatically in Oslo?
If yes, does that mean I will go through customs in Alta? Do the smaller regional airports in Norway have facilities for that? How does that work?
Edit: It seems it's possible to transfer?

No first hand experience with the process, but https://avinor.no/en/airport/oslo-airport/plan-your-trip/transfer/domestic-transfer seems to indicate that it depends on the airlines involved rather than the destination airport.

@jcaron Norwegian Air, like it says in OP

Oslo is one of the few airports with separate "domestic" and "Schengen" sectors. To get to the domestic sector you pass customs. But what I saw there is that you do not have to pick up your luggage. You have to wait till it appears on a screen say, yes that is my luggage, and only if customs takes an interest in your bags are they inspected.

In you case, you should not need to handle your luggage at all in Oslo.
Avinor, the Oslo Airport operator, tell us:

DOMESTIC TRANSFER
With domestic transfer, you can arrive from abroad with certain airlines and fly onward domestically without collecting your luggage. Remember to check with your airline what applies to your journey. When using our Domestic Transfer solution, only travelers with through tickets can use the solution.
If you are coming from abroad and are headed further on a domestic flight, there are different rules for transfers based on which airline you are traveling with and where you are arriving from.
In order to use domestic transfer, you must have booked a ticket with an onward connection where the entire journey is with the airlines SAS, Norwegian, Widerøe or Emirates†. Domestic transfer is open from 07:00 – 23:00 every day.
†Applies only to travel in combination with SAS or Widerøe.
If you arrive in Norway with an airline other than SAS, Norwegian, Widerøe or Emirates and are going to fly further with a domestic flight, you must go down to the arrival hall, collect and deliver any luggage, and go through the security check in the departure hall.This also applies to passengers who only travel with hand luggage.

(follows a list of airline combinations, which includes Norwegian -> Norwegian)

Checklist for using domestic transfer

Your journey is with the airlines or combination of airlines mentioned in the table above.
The journey in its entirety is on the same day/date, and within the period 7am – 11pm.
Your baggage tag is marked with your final destination and not "OSL".
Your baggage does not consist of animals or weapons.

From the following destinations, you cannot use a domestic transfer:

Norwegian: Bastia, Bilbao, Burgas, Dubrovnik, Ibiza, Malta, Palanga, Pula, Salzburg, Sarajevo, Skopje, Split, Tirana, Tivat, Varna and Zagreb.
SAS: Dubrovnik, Tivat, Pula, Salzburg, Split.

How to use domestic transfer

Follow the signs marked either "transfer" or "connecting flights" when you get off the plane.
Next to gate D2 you will find a yellow area marked "domestic transfer".
In the same area, there is a tax-free shop where you can buy tax-free goods before going through customs.
Scan your ticket/boarding pass at the boarding scan and proceed through customs.
When you have passed customs, you will enter the departure hall for domestic flights. Check the information screens for which gate your next flight is departing from and then follow the signs.


This is confirmed in this video:

Restricted domestic transfer:



Going through customs without luggage:


At 6:53 in the video they tell us:

So, a note about the luggage. Just before passing customs or the gates there we scanned our boarding pass and as you scan your boarding pass it asks whether you have luggage or not where you reply
yes of course if you have luggage in the hold, and then a photo of your luggage comes and you just have to confirm that it's yours. Once you've confirmed it the luggage will be transferred directly to your domestic destination.

Note that this scheme was probably relatively new at the time of that video (November 2021).
In their case, they did:

EU/Schengen arrivals
Security
Walk quite a bit through the Schengen departures area
Go through customs without bags
Domestic departures area

Your itinerary through the airport will be slightly different as you are arriving from outside Schengen and will have to go through passport control.

You go through customs at entrance to Norway, in this case in Oslo. You will have to pick up your luggage on a belt in OSL, walk through customs (very quick, since they stop hardly anyone), go upstairs, check luggage in for the last leg, and finally go through the security check as if you were travelling just from Oslo.
There might be exceptions to this, but ever since Oslo Gardermoen was constructed I've always gone through the process described above.

Which airlines have you been doing this with?

According to Avinor, it should be possible https://avinor.no/en/airport/oslo-airport/plan-your-trip/transfer/domestic-transfer

SAS and Norwegian, at least. But why not ask them directly?

Interesting. I have never experienced that at any  international to Schengen connection.  In my case luggage was always checked through to final destination.

When your final destination in Europe is an airport that has a customs presence (which is the case for most airports) you indeed pass customs after picking up your luggage. But Norway has a lot of small airports that aren't even staffed...

@KristvanBesien With the 'domestic transfer' program on Gardermoen Airport, your luggage will be inspected by customs in Oslo, usually without your presence. It is irrelevant if the Norwegian airport you are continuing to has a customs office or not.

I also had to do bring my checked in luggage to the connecting flight myself flying with SAS on the route FRA->OSL->TRD.
